# JQuery toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tofixed

I have this JavaScript code:

```
if($('#numlic').val() <= 10) {
    $('#totalprice').text(23.10 * $('#numlic').val()).toFixed(2);
}
```

but it doesn't work and I get the "toFixed is not a function" error.
Can you help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a simple typo:

```
if($('#numlic').val() <= 10) {
    $('#totalprice').text((23.10 * $('#numlic').val()).toFixed(2));
}
```

The [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function is an extension of a `Number`. You're trying to set the element `$('#totalprice')` `.toFixed(2)`, when you want to set the result of "`23.10 * $('#numlic').val()`".